# how to configure Firefox to automatically reuse the login credentials like IE

Tags: http, firefox, authentication, digest

Multiple HTTP Authentication Prompts in Firefox
We are currently working on porting our application from Internet Explorer to Firefox and the application currently uses HTTP Digest Authentication. In case of Internet Explorer, the popup dialog to enter the Username/password appears only once and the entered login credentials are reused for subsequent HTTP requests to the web server. However in case of Firefox, the Authentication popups appears whenever the request is made to the Web Server. The Web Server used is Emweb Server.

We would like to know how to configure Firefox to automatically reuse the login credentials like IE.

Comment: Shouldn't the popup have a checkbox to remember the password? Does it keep prompting for it even if you check that?

Comment: The default configuration of Firefox should do that (remember your authentication) within the same "session" (whether you ask it to remember the password for later or not). I'd recommend installing Firebug and snooping on the traffic (particularly the `Authorization` header) to see if there's some issue with the authentication, such as setting a really short timeout or some such.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable NTLM Configuration within FireFox.  It is very simple to do and should solve your problem:

1. Open Firefox and type “about:config” in the address bar. (without the quotes of course)
2. In the ‘Filter’ field type the following “network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris”
3. Double click the name of the preference that we just searched for
4. Enter the URLs of the sites you wish to pass NTLM auth info to in the form of:

   http://intranet.company.com,http://email.company.lan
5. Notice that you can use a comma separated list in this field.

Comment: Clumsily but works! Thanks!